# Why does Markdown relative image is not render on Github?

Tags: image, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

My Markdown relative image isn't rendering.

I tried example from [GitHub guides](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/):

```
![Image of Yaktocat](https://octodex.github.com/images/yaktocat.png)
```

But it isn't rendering. Image is available.

Also I tried HTML `<img src="">` syntax, it works as expected. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
# DataScience internship task
<br/>
How to run: python3 new_tool.py
<br/>
<br/>
Screenshot:
<br/>
![ProgressBar](screen.png)
<br/>
<img src="/screen.png">
```

The first image doesn't load, but the second one does.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<br/>`.

Markdown has its own way of creating paragraph breaks. Instead, just leave a blank line:

```
# DataScience internship task

How to run: python3 new_tool.py

Screenshot:

![ProgressBar](screen.png)
```

Comment: Thx a lot. So the problem is in mixing Markdown with plain HTML?

Comment: Markdown supports inline HTML (though on GitHub some tags and attributes are restricted). Keeping block-level elements (and HTML separated from Markdown) separated by a blank line is usually a good idea. In this case it appears to be required.